# Cannot infer generic type if it is returned

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, type-inference

I have a very simple extension method (it's probably irrelevant though that it is extension and would be the same for ordinary ones):

```
public static T Content<T>(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var content = (ObjectContent<T>) response.Content;
    return (T) content.Value;
}
```

Now I do use it like that:

```
MyContent content = response.Content();
```

But I get the error that type cannot be inferred from the usage, so I have to do this:

```
MyContent content = response.Content<MyContent>();
```

Is this just a missing feature that it cannot infer or I am doing something wrong here? I don't see any problems with inferring that `T` is of type `MyContent` even without explicitly saying so, though of course I did not write the compiler and don't know all the details.

Comment: If you don't give it a type parameter, how would it ever know what type it needs to use?  I don't get it...

Comment: How should the compiler know that you´re referring `MyContent` when everything it knows is the provided `response` which is of type `HttpResponseMessage`? I assume you mix *run-time* with *compile-time*, where generics work at compile-time.

Comment: @rory.ap - By inferring it from the type on the left hand side

Comment: The compiler definitely checks the type already to verify that you can even assign it, so why not go further and allow the type inference based on that?

Comment: Don't understand people downvoting for no obvious reason. Seems perfectly legit question to me that was not asked before (at least I have not found the answer).

Comment: You are mixing `MyClass` and `MyContent`, shouldn't that be the same? Or perhaps `MyClass` derives from `MyContent`, if so then add that?

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for the note, it was just a mistype that probably confused people, fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't see any problems with inferring that T is of type MyClass even without explicitly saying so

Well, the problem is that the language isn't specified that way at all. Generic type inference is performed based on the arguments. A method invocation expression is a kind of expression that always has a type - and resolving which method overload is being used and what the generic type arguments are is part of establishing that type. How the result is used is simply *not* part of overload resolution or type inference.

It *is* used when performing conversions from anonymous functions, method groups and the null literal - those are expressions which don't have types in themselves, but are merely convertible to the appropriate type.

To cut a long story short: you need to specify the type argument.

Note that you don't need to write the compiler to get all the details - that's what the language specification is for. The most recently published specification is [C# 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029).

Comment: Is there anything theoretically preventing the compiler from inferring the type? Or it's just simply not done for C#?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: It's not a matter of the compiler, it's a matter of the language design. That change would make the language *much, much* more complicated - imagine we weren't just calling the method and assigning it to a variable, but passing it as a call to another generic method that returned the same type... there's have to be a whole chain of inference. I'm heartily glad that the compiler *doesn't* do this. Type inference is a hairy enough bit of the spec already, without this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do understand that it's a matter of language design. What I really meant is: are there any theoretical (not practical problems) that prevent this type of inference? Or it was just too complicated/error-prone/time-consuming to implement?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: That's too broad a question to really answer, because you could decide exactly how complicated to make the feature. If you wanted to only cope with the *direct* "call a method, assign it to a variable" then I suspect it would be feasible. Beyond that it's hard to predict.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems I was not wrong thinking that it's a feasible feature (in this limited case at least :))

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: A lot of things are "feasible if you don't mind all kinds of other negative consequences" (such as massive language spec complications which may limit which other features can be introduced later).